# Resistor type and value

Tags: resistors

I have removed a section of electric underfloor heating mat and need to substitute the removed section with a resistor to bring up to the correct resistance for manufacturer specification.

I know the ohm value i need but i think something that can disipate the heat will be needed and not that familiar with resistors.

Comment: Use the underfloor heating mat, it is a resistor with the correct value and ability to dissipate the appropriate amount of power.

Comment: What you need is not clear to us, and repair questions are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

If you are so unfamiliar with electronics to not even know what a resistor does, you shouldn't be messing with house wiring.

Get a real electrician to take care of whatever it is you are trying to do.  I wouldn't try to tell you how to do this even if we could decipher exactly what that was.

Comment: This is a comment rather than an answer to the technical question. Recommend you vtc question.

Comment: @Tony: Technically you are right since the OP never actually asked anything.  However, this is the "answer" he needs to hear.  Sometimes people ask (or imply) the wrong question.  Responding with the right way to address the issue can still be useful.  I understand the downvote, but I'm leaving this answer here.  I suspect the whole question will be closed soon anyway.

Comment: Sure and nothing personal :-)

Answer (score 3):

Can Electric Underfloor Heating be cut?

No. It is important that the correct size heater is installed based on the available space as the heating cable cannot be cut. A certified electrician should be consulted for advice on extending the cable

Answer (score 2):

I'd just go with the answer "Don't do it". If you're not familiar with simple resistors, than **do not play with mains.** You might set your house alight, or electrocute someone.

Comment: While this is the most sensible advice, it doesn't answer the OP's question, and is maybe better as a comment. I agree with you 100% though.